# Относительное прилагательное от названия города Риека (Хорватия)

Tags: словообразование

Добрый день, уважаемое сообщество! Подскажите, как образовать относительное прилагательное от названия хорватского города Риека.

Answer (score 1):

**Риекский**. Ср. [Риекский залив в БСЭ](http://m.slovari.yandex.ru/article.xml?book=bse&title=%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2)